# Cannot install ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap, rjson

I have been getting this every time I try to install `ggmap`:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Julianne/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘rjson’ is not available
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/ggmap_3.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4698501 bytes (4.5 MB)
downloaded 4.5 MB
package ‘ggmap’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Julianne\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUTtA97\downloaded_packages
```

I have installed Rtools but still cannot install `ggmap` or `rjson`.

Comment: Make sure Rtools are in your PATH. This means that whichever tool is using them will be able to find them. There are several ways of doing this. See [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html) to learn how to do it from R.

Comment: Other steps that might help if Roman Luštrik's link doesn't finish it for you: restart RStudio and/or restart windows. BTW: R-3.6 is a bit outdated, I suggest updating to R-4.0 or R-4.1 (fyi,  R-4.2 is expected early/mid 2022, I believe).

Comment: I believe the current version of RTools requires R version 4.0 or higher. So unless you went in the archive to install an older version, you may need to update R for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've installed an even newer version of R and it's all working okay now!